# How to add a tenant remotely in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 Identity Server and I'm using the APIs from UserStoreManager. I want to let a super admin be able to add a tenant remotely but I cannot seem to find an addTenant API. Also, I want to make admin/user of one tenant to be added as admin/user of another tenant instead of creating a new username everytime. I cannot figure out how to do so. What is the correct way to go forward with this? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first requirement you can use the `registerTenant` method in `TenantMgtService` Web Service.

The second requirement is not supported out of the box. It can be achieved by having a flat user structure in the LDAP. The flat user sructure will be as follows; All the users of tenants will be in a single OU called Users. Tenant OU will only have Groups (which are roles in the sense of Carbon Servers)

```
dc=WSO2,dc=ORG
|--OU=Users
|  |--admin
|  |--user1
|  |--user2
|  |...    
|--OU=Groups
|--OU=tenantone.org
|  |--OU=Groups
|  |  |...
| ... 
|  
|
```

For the above you will have to write your own [Tenant manager](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0010/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/tenant/CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager.java), [Realm Configuration Bulder](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0010/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/config/multitenancy/CommonLDAPRealmConfigBuilder.java) and a [User Store Manager](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0010/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap/ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java).